# CodeIgniter - Subir archivo mediate un formulario

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

Estoy un poco desesperado ya, porque estoy haciendo un proyecto en CodeIgniter el cual es una tienda Online de productos de alimentación. El caso es que cuando tengo que crear el producto, tengo un formulario en el que se solicita al administrador que introduzca, el Nombre, Marca, Descripción, Precio, IVA, Categoría, etc. del producto y entre medias, hay otro campo que es el de la **imagen del producto**. Pues cuando relleno ese formulario y lo envío, el producto se mete en ella base de datos y funciona todo genial, excepto que la imagen del producto **no se copia** de mi disco duro a la carpeta del servidor.

Os pongo el código de este formulario (la vista), el cual he cambiado ya tantas veces, que debe haber errores de sobremanera:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php if (isset($error)) {?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <?php echo validation_errors('<div class="container"><b><ul><li>','</li></ul></b></div>') ?>
        </div>
    <?php }?>       
    <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-body">
            <h3 style='margin-left: 4em'>Crear Producto</h3>
            <h6 style='margin-left: 8em'>Rellena los siguientes campos con los datos del producto y una vez termines pulsa el botón.</h6>
            <hr>
            <?php echo form_open('Inicio/verificarProducto'); ?>
            <div class="row">

                <div style='margin-left: 6em' class="container">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user">Nombre *</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?=set_value('nombre')?>" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre del Producto" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pass">Descripción *</label>
                            <input type="text" name="descripcion" value="<?=set_value('descripcion')?>" class="form-control" id="descripcion" placeholder="Descripción del Producto" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div></div><hr>

                <div style='margin-left: 6em' class="container">

                    <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <form action="subir" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <label for="image">Imagen *</label>

                                <input type="file" name="imagen" action="<?=base_url("subir_controller/subir")?>" method="post" value="<?=set_value('imagen')?>" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
[MÁS CODIGO DEL RESTO DE LOS DATOS]
                </div>  

                <hr>
                <a class="btn btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 50px;" href="<?=site_url().'/Inicio/cargarVista/panel_usuario_admin'?>"><b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Volver atrás</b></a></center><button style='margin-left: 7em' type="submit" name="bcontinuar" class="btn btn-success"><B>Finalizar</B>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button><br>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php echo form_close() ?>
    </div>
```

Por aquí el el fragmento del controlador encargado del formulario:

```
public function verificarProducto()
{
  $prueba = $this->mproducto->verCategoriasEx($this->input->post('categoria'));

  if($this->mproducto->verCategoriasEx($this->input->post('categoria')) >= 0){
    $a = intval($this->mproducto->verCategoriasEx($this->input->post('categoria')));
  }else{
    $datos_cat = array(
      'nombre' => $this->input->post('categoria'),
      'descripcion' => "",
      'anuncio' => 0,
      'mostrar' => 1
    );

    $a = $this->mproducto->insertaCategoria($datos_cat);
  }


  $datos = array(
    'categoria_id' => $a ,
    'nombre' => $this->input->post('nombre'),
    'marca' => $this->input->post('marca'),
    'descripcion' => $this->input->post('descripcion'),
    'descuento' => 0,
    'anuncio' => 0,
    'imagen' => $this->input->post('imagen'),
    'pvp' => $this->input->post('pvp'),
    'iva' => $this->input->post('iva'),
    'stock' => $this->input->post('stock'),
    'mostrar' => 1,
    'finicio_dest' => $this->input->post('finicio_dest'),
    'ffin_dest' => $this->input->post('ffin_dest'),
    'destacado' => 1
  );
  $this->mproducto->insertaProducto($datos);
  $cuerpo = $this->load->view("producto_creado", "", TRUE);
  $this->cargaPlantilla($cuerpo, "");
}
```

Por aquí el el fragmento del controlador encargado de la subida de la imagen:

```
<?php
if(!defined('BASEPATH'))
  exit('No direct script access allowed');

class subir_controller extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
}

public function index(){ 
  $this->load->view('nuevoProducto', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

public function subir(){
  $dato = $this->input->post("txt_dato");
  $nombre_imagen = $_FILES['archivoImagen']['name'];
  $data = array("dato" => $dato, "imagen" => $nombre_imagen);
  $guardar = $this->msubir->guardar($data);
  $this->subirImagen();
}   

public function subirImagen(){
  $nombreCompleto = $_FILES['archivoImagen']['name'];
  $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/productos/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
  $config['file_name'] = $nombreCompleto;
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  if(!$this->upload->do_upload('archivoImagen')) {
    $data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
  } else {
    $data['infoImagen'] = $this->upload->data();
  }
}
}
?>
```

Y por último, el modelo aquí:

```
<?php
class Subir_model extends CI_Model
{
    function guardar($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert("subir", $data);
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Llevo ya mucho tiempo intentando cosas y seguramente de la mezcla de soluciones que he intentado, haya algo por el código que no tenga mucho sentido, pero ahora mismo, funciona tal y como os comento en la parte de arriba de la pregunta. Guarda en la base de datos **todos** los datos, incluido el nombre de la imagen, pero **no** copia la imagen a la carpeta del servidor.

Os agradezco vuestra ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

es posible que ya sea tarde en responder, de igual modo dejo la respuesta, estas colocando doble formulario en tu ejemplo, hay uno que es el de la imagen que no cierra, puedes hacerlo todo en un solo proceso de envio, te muestro como lo he logrado, solo coloca un formulario, debes cambiar la funcion `form_open()`

> De la guia de [codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)
>
> form_open_multipart()
>
> Esta función es idéntica a la `form_open()`, excepto que agrega un atributo multiparte, > que es necesario si desea utilizar el formulario para cargar archivos.

debes cambiar de:

```
<?php echo form_open('Inicio/verificarProducto'); ?>
```

a:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Inicio/verificarProducto'); ?>
```

lo que te generara lo siguiente:

```
<form action="Inicio/verificarProducto" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

luego en tu model cuando procesas el formulario, puedes verificar la imagen de la siguiente manera y luego cargarla:

```
// si hay una imagen cargamos
if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
   // verificamos nombre
   if (empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
       return null;
   }
    // APPPATH te dará la ruta a la carpeta de la aplicación de codeigniter.
    // realpath() te dará la url real sin el ../
    $upload_config = array(
        'upload_path'   => realpath('./uploads/'),  // carpeta de ruta
        'file_name'     => '__img_' . uniqid(),  // nombre de archivo
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png', // tipo de imagen
    );
    // cargamos libreria upload
    $this->load->library('upload', $upload_config);
    // intentamos cargar la imagen
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
        $img_upload = $this->upload->data();
        // devolvemos la ruta absoluta
        if (isset($img_upload['full_path'])) {
            return $img_upload;
        }
        return null;
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->upload->display_errors());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos!